# How to shift career from embedded to applications?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, job-change

I am planning to shift my career from embedded to applications.
I have around 10 years of experience in C, C++, Qt, and Linux. I want to work in a big firms
like banking institution. Also, I feel that I am good in applications - business logic rather than
lower level programming. I have got more appreciataion when I have accomplished application job.
I think that my brain looks for different options when working in application. Thus, I want
to move to application side. Also, I want to focus more on business logic rather than programming
tool like - C, driver programming. My question is what language I should learn keeping in mind
my experience on Linux, C, C++ don't get wasted. I thought of Java but Java is quite big and
there is a good chance that I may be lost. Also, it needs a lot of dedicated time to learn.
I already know python and I think python is not suitable for big firms. So, I am refraining from python.
Next is .net. I work in New Zealand and the market is good for C#. But, the problem is that 
if I will learn C# then my linux knowledge will get wasted. I think I will be able to use my C++
knowledge. So, I will not be able to get advantage of my linux skill sets. So, I am confused
what I should learn. I want a realistic goal so that I can jump into the field which will pay me
equivalent to what I am getting paid now.

Comment: `Java is quite big and there is a good chance that I may be lost. Also, it needs a lot of dedicated time to learn.` ... Then you don't know C++ yet. Maybe that's the reason why it is no fun? Struggling with everything (maybe even without realizing it)...

Comment: About "what should I learn". Don't know, and there won't be a single true answer. Search job offers you like most, and see what they want. We can't tell you that.

Comment: Yet another comment: `python is not suitable for big firms` Nonsense. `C# ... Linux .. wasted` Mono.

Comment: If you are willing to invest the time, apply at a big firm for an embedded systems job, mention your interest in applications, and see if they will work with you to build the experience so you can shift jobs in the company.

Comment: I found C++ more difficult to pick up than Java. Their syntax is similar; you should have no problem picking Java up with your experience with C and C++. Go for it. Try Codecademy if you need a push to learn the language. It provides coding exercises so you code as you learn.

Comment: I am scared that there are so many things in Java to learn - core java isn't enough. I may need to learn a lot of things in Java  - like different frameworks whereas .net will be not very vast. However, my linux experience will get wasted there.

Comment: As I told you already, .NET programs can run on Linux. Your knowledge will not be wasted. And again, stop thinking that Java is the most complicated language. Java and .NET are comparable, and C++ is the real big thing. (However, I don't believe anymore that you know enough about C++, to understand how huge the language and environment really is)

Comment: Career advice is off topic, voting to close.

Comment: Core Java is just the name of a book. No matter what language you use, you will need more than the knowledge of one book to get serious work done. Though it is not a bad book.

Answer (score 2):

1. Browse job openings on career sites and find companies you would like to work for
2. See what technologies they require
3. Go write a few hundred lines of code in said technology
4. Interview off of your extensive experience in whatever plus your basic familiarity in and willingness to learn said technology
5. Repeat

That's...  basically the formula. Sorry to be blunt but your question contains a lot of nonsense:

> My question is what language I should learn keeping in mind my experience on Linux, C, C++ don't get wasted.

A coworker in my first training class was a biologist who completed her Ph.D. and discovered she was extremely allergic to lab mice. She became a programmer. You can deal with the transition too.

> I thought of Java but Java is quite big and there is a good chance that I may be lost. Also, it needs a lot of dedicated time to learn.

This is the most confusing sentence in your whole question. Programmers are paid money to learn hard things. So...  yeah? That's going to be something you're going to have to do.

> I already know python and I think python is not suitable for big firms.

I don't know where you get this idea. It's used in many companies, just like many other technologies are used in many companies.

> work in New Zealand and the market is good for C#. But, the problem is that if I will learn C# then my linux knowledge will get wasted.

**That's not how knowledge works.** Go learn any other OS or shell on the basis of your extensive Linux experience. That's not "wasting" it. Also, who cares, go get a job you like and waste whatever you need to.